# node js Filter CSV Row based on Column Content

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse

I am trying to filter a CSV file on load and have got the following so far:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('Names.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
      // If Column 2 Is 6
      // If Column 3 is Y
    console.log(row);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
  });
```

If have searched everywhere for a reference / starting point but not making much progress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks to get the result of filtered rows:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
function getFilteredData(y, callback){ 
    const result = [];                 
    fs.createReadStream('Names.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
          const headers = Object.keys(row);
          if(Number(row[headers[1]]) === 6 && row[headers[2]] === y )
              result.push(row)
       })
      .on('end', () => {
          console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
          callback(result)
       });
}
```

or if you want to have it as a stream you need to write a transform stream or a duplex stream

Comment: Feels like a step in the right direction.  If I replace the If statement with console.log(row[1]) the output is 'Undefined'